# ExpressJS/AngularJS views routing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

There is some AngularJS routing:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
          resolve: {
            postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
              return posts.getAll();
            }]
          }
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```

This routing is at 'root/public/javascripts/app.js'. So, I store home.html 'root/views/home.js'.

My ExpressJS app file contains this string:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

But when I execute my application I get error: 404 for '/home.html'. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try 'views/home.html' or '/views/home.html'? i think the first one would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TemplateUrl is an Angular template that should be located in your public folder. So templateUrl `/home.html` will resolve to `/root/public/home.html`, not `/root/views/home.html`. I feel that's where the problem is, given the info you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `templateUrl: '/home.html'` with `templateUrl: 'views/home.html'` (or maybe `/views/home.html`). Currently it is not taking the `home.html` in the views folder.